# Facing problems with UTM

Tags: virtual-machine

How to copy & paste stuff from host machine to guest operating system in UTM?
I'm using m1 mac and I surfed over Internet for a while but can't find a solution with UTM in it

Comment: There some spice tool thingy you can find it on utm's official site under Window's section or Ubuntu section. just run it in guest machine and you're good to go. [here](https://mac.getutm.app/support/)

Comment: @Ameya doesn't work :( spice-vdagent is running, but it still isn't pasting anything

Comment: @EmileZäkiev I think in the recent update they fixed the clipboard issue could you please check again?

Comment: @Ameya thanks for the info, I just checked their latest release [changelog](https://github.com/utmapp/UTM/releases/tag/v4.1.5) and see no changes about the clipboard support. As far as I'm concerned the problem lied in my wish to use the copy-pasting functionality with a Ubuntu **Server** guest OS (i.e. no GUI). Which I confirmed [directly](https://github.com/utmapp/UTM/issues/1204) with the UTM's developers to not be possible, as it requires X11 to work.

Answer (score 0):

To have copy-paste enabled in UTM for macOS with ARM64 M1 or M2, you can connect to your guest OS via "Screen Sharing", where copy-paste is enabled.

To enable Screen Sharing on macOS guest OS:

1. Start your guest macOS in UTM
2. Go to Settings->Sharing->"Screen Sharing" in your guest macOS, enable Screen Sharing.

To connect to your host OS, you have 2 alternatives:

1. On your guest OS Look for the vnc://192.x.x.x address shown in the System Preferences -> Share -> Screen Sharing info page.
2. On your host macOS run Spotlight Search (Command–Space
   bar key combination) and type the vnc://192.x.x.x or similar adress
   from guest Screen Sharing info page. Press Enter/Return key. Type
   you guest macOS user name and password and press Enter/Return.

or

1. Open finder on your host OS, click on Network in the left side bar.
2. You should see the VM you just configured in the list, open the network computer and look for the "Share Screen..." button top right.

Now copy paste should work in the Remote Screen interface.

To share files between guest and host OS, you can enable System Preferences -> Sharing -> File sharing on your guest OS and connect via network share from host to guest.

Comment: Upvoted this answer because it seems to be the lowest effort and minimal additional software solution to the problem of being about to use a shared clipboard with UTM.

Answer (score -3):

You can send yourself an email with the text and open it inside the vitual machine